# Create IF formula in a cell, with VBA, where result can be blank

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to fill the cell to say =if(d5>0,D5*1.05,"") but I can not figure out how to have the false part of the statement fill in blank.

```
blank = ""
For i = 5 To 44
    Range("G" & i).Formula = "=V" & i
    Range("E" & i).Formula = "=IF(D" & i & ">0,D" & i & "*1.05," & blank & " )"
Next
```

Comment: You can escape the double quotes in different ways, for example, with Chr(34). Replace blank with  Chr(34) & Chr(34)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned by other posters, doubling a double quote when building a string will result in a single double quote character. Since you need 2 consecutive double quotes in the "else" part of your IF, type 4 of them.

What I'd like to now point out is that *you don't need to loop over rows* to accomplish what you're doing. You can set the `Formula` property for a range, building the formula as it should appear in the range's top left cell, and it will propagate automagically:

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub DoTheFormulaThing()
    Range("G5:G44").Formula = "=V5"
    Range("E5:E44").Formula = "=IF(D5>0,D5*1.05,"""")"
End Sub
```

When necessary, just put `$` in the right places for absolute references.

Comment: That is actually really helpful. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Or use double quotes directly …

```
For i = 5 To 44
    Range("G" & i).Formula = "=V" & i
    Range("E" & i).Formula = "=IF(D" & i & ">0,D" & i & "*1.05,"""")"
Next
```

Comment: `text(,)` also produces a zero-length string and can be used instead of `""""`.